# Upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS still does not work

Tags: upgrade, updates

I do not understand why upgrading still doesn't work, the installer suggests it has to do with network, no such thing, stable as a rock. Is there a work around without loosing the present state? Is there anything I can do?

Output 1: terminal `apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid InRelease    
Hit:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty InRelease       
Get:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4.316 B]
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dupeguru/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Get:11 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2.961 B]         
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/nobetas/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/sab-addons/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/pan/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/speed-dreams/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Err:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
Hit:20 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-ppa/backports/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid Release [14,0 kB]
Get:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty Release [74,7 kB]
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/pan/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/speed-dreams/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Get:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid Release.gpg [316 B]
Get:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty Release.gpg [316 B]
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid Release.gpg
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/pan/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/speed-dreams/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: E4DFEC907DEDA4B8A670E8042836CB0A8AC93F7A
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu lucid Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty Release: The following signatures were invalid: 06D1ED00EB802A66640696C8D0AFF96872D340A3
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output 2: terminal `rob@rob-asus-I5-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bolt curl libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 standard security updates
Need to get 1.206 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.641 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 tzdata all 2022c-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 [288 kB]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.10.1~20.04.1 [146 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 bolt amd64 0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1 [143 kB]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13 [161 kB]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13 [235 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13 [233 kB]
Fetched 1.206 kB in 0s (2.708 kB/s)      
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 410684 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-tzdata_2022c-0ubuntu0.20.04.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2022c-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) over (2022a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.10.1~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.10.1~20.04.1) over (27.9~20.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-bolt_0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bolt (0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1) over (0.8-4ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) ...
Setting up tzdata (2022c-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'
Local time is now:      vr  2 sep 2022 12:56:51 CEST.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Sep  2 10:56:51 UTC 2022.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.10.1~20.04.1) ...
Setting up bolt (0.9.1-2~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
bolt.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
```

Comment: We will need clear details to understand the situation well enough to attempt to answer. Please edit your question and include more details and context. As currently written, it's not clear what is the exact problem you are encountering. To describe your problem, please tell us exactly what steps are needed to reproduce the problem. You should tell us what you expected, and then tell us exactly how the problem manifests. Include whole error messages verbatim. Avoid paraphrasing. If we have to guess at details, it reduces the chance that we can provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Understood, however it will remain quite shallow as it happens when the auto upgrade function finishes. The ask is if I want to upgrade and I answer with YES. At one point in this process it reads 203 packages that need upgrading and subsequently the process halts at 201. Comment made is that it 'probably' has to do with network, not the case, read the router and I have more than 2,5 years up time over here. But no worries, I will simply stay on the current build.

Comment: I never said "Don't upgrade". Actually the opposite - don't ignore these kinds of problems because they will snowball and get worse. What I said was that you need to add clear and specific details so we can help. You paraphrase: the "installer suggests" things and you give pseudo details like "it reads 203 packages", but details are incomplete. Don't paraphrase- we won't recognize. Use the exact phrasing as your system. Based on this comment, it seems you might have problems with apt. I suggest that you edit your question and add the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: I don't see any errors when you run `sudo apt upgrade` - so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Artur: Origin of "my" problem is the fact that the Ubuntu upgrade mechanism halts halfway. I have searched for a reason but couldn't find any.

Comment: Your sources list is jam-packed with errors. Fix that.

Comment: OK, thanks, could you point me to how I can? No idea how to work the sources list. I know where it is, but unable to edit so far

Comment: It is so messed up it's hard to know where to start. You have sources from at least three Ubuntu releases (focal, jaunty, lucid) as well as a dozen or so ppas. A first step may be to go to Software &Updates / Other Software and remove all the broken ppas shown in the `apt update` output. Or, you could use `ppa-purge` but honestly I don't know if it even works on a broken ppa. The difficulty arises in that just removing the source doesn't remove the software you have installed from that source.

Comment: OK, that clarifies. My machine is running fine and even a lot faster than a while ago so I will perform a fresh install once needed. I will not try to bend my head on how I got to these awkward installs, they are there. Good help provided, do I need to do anything to close this?